# Don't see the opiton for target Windows Phone OS 7.5 on the Visual Studio 2010 express for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I installed the Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update , but I don't see the opiton for target Windows Phone OS 7.5 on the Visual Studio 2010 express for Windows Phone when I create a new application. Would someone tell me which software I need in order to create the application for target Windows Phone OS 7.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.5 is the same as OS version 7.10.x.

> *Windows Phone 7.5 is the official product name we use to describe this release. However, due to a quirk of software development, the actual OS version is technically identified as 7.10.7720. You'll see both of these names on your phone in Settings > About > More info.